# Code Review in C: Where is my mistake trying to solve this simple riddle?

Tags: c, c99

I'm trying to do a simple problem in C that goes like this:

> Any integer `P`, such that `0 < P < N`, splits this tape into two non-empty parts: `A[0]`, `A[1]`, ..., `A[P − 1]` and `A[P]`, `A[P + 1]`, ..., `A[N − 1]`.
>   The difference between the two parts is the value of: `|(A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[P − 1]) − (A[P] + A[P + 1] + ... + A[N − 1])|`
>   In other words, it is the absolute difference between the sum of the first part and the sum of the second part.
>
> Also:
>   `N` is an integer within the range `[2..100,000]`;
>   each element of array `A` is an integer within the range `[−1,000..1,000]`.

I came up with the following code:

```
int solution(int A[], int N) {
// write your code in C99
double firstSum = A[0];
double secondSum = 0;

double curDiff, maxDiff, maxIndex = 1;

for(int i = 1; i < N; i++)
{
    secondSum += A[i];
}

curDiff = abs(firstSum - secondSum);
maxDiff = curDiff;

for(int i = 2; i < N; i++)
{
    secondSum -= A[i-1];
    firstSum += A[i-1];
    curDiff = abs(firstSum - secondSum);
    if(curDiff > maxDiff)
        maxIndex = i;
}
return maxIndex;
}
```

Which, according to the site I did this test on, is really bad. The site says the code failed most of the tests they ran, but I can't figure out why (they don't supply the tests). The code seems fine to me. Furthermore, they said that a solution is to be O(n) worst case space complexity (not including input) and I've managed to do it in O(1), so something seems off.

Comment: You have 2 for loops that iterate over the N elements of an array. That seems like O(n) to me

Comment: "Code Review" in the title? You do know that there's [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)?

Comment: It seems weird.. on the website where this was given I got that the code only completed one test case correctly...

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis You're referring to time complexity. The website mentions space complexity.

Comment: Either I don't understand the problem description, or you haven't told us what `solution` is supposed to calculate ;)

Comment: @Rhymoid you are right, just noticed the reference to space complexity. Solving this challenge does require allocating an array. So the site is correct at allowing such a space complexity for the solution

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis Without Googling the original problem statement, I'm still not sure what the question is, so I don't know if it is correct. If it's not the maximum difference we're looking for (which would just require O(1) space), the specification for `solution` is not in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return the wrong value. They are looking for the minimal difference and not for P of the minimal difference. You can pick a solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25198726/tape-equilibrium-codility-training-program) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455058/tape-equilibrium-codility-training) or [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/44371/tape-equilibrium) in a language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help everyone. I noticed that I didn't update maxDiff, thereby throwing me off. Thanks again!